# Operation pass missions

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I wanted to buy one of the older operation passes to do the campaign and was wondering, if you buy an access pass AFTER the operation ends, can you still do the campaign and get the drops?

Answer (score 1):

No, buying and using the access pass after the campaign has supposedly ended, only yields a operation coin. Beyond that there will be no missions or awards to pick up. However, cases from these operation "seasons" can occasionally drop during gameplay, tho it is rare. So, in the end, buying an access pass for an expired operation season is pointless unless you want to collect the coin(s).

Comment: THank you, I've wanted to buy the breakout mission pack for a while but my friend says you cant get the missions.

Comment: Sorry, your friend is actually right and I was wrong. I edited my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Once the operation is over, buying and using the pass will only result in a bronze operation coin.

There is no way to work on the missions or get the associated rewards.